# How to focus an image in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

How to focus an image in Silverlight?

For example: imagine that when my page loads, It will focus on a texbox, so I don't have to click in there to control. I want the same with image control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to make a button of the image and than set the button with the default focus.

[Make a button with an image](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/116148/261880.aspx)

[Set button with focus](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/14537/361892.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

There is no way for an Image to acquire input focus directly.

Input focus is supported only on `Control`s and its descendants which have the properties `IsEnabled` and `IsTabStop` set to `true`. Image is derived from `FrameworkElement`, not from `Control`, so it's not technically a control.

You could create a `UserControl` that contains the image and then call `.Focus()` on the container control.

Comment: Thank you, but this did not work for my purpose. In my case, I have a image that will do something when I MouseWheel. I always need to click on the image before start the behavior.